# How to query to Firestore sub document

Tags: android, firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an app and I would like to query Firestore sub document. Let me explain further.

1. I have a collection of documents where cars are stored, each document has a particular car with description.
2. In each of those documents above, I av a sub collection called `user_data` which have it's own document where a particular userid of the user who add the car to his wishlist is stored.

Now I want to get the document of cars if a userid is present in its sub collection. In short, I want to get the wishlist of a particular user.
I'm using streambuilder with listviewbuilder but the problem is how do I perform this query?

Or is there any simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries in Firestore are shallow, which means they only get items from the collection that the query is run against. There is no way to get documents from a top-level collection and other collections or subcollections in a single query. Firestore doesn't support queries across different collections in one step. So you cannot get items from a collection based on the items that exist within a subcollection. A single query may only use properties of documents in a single collection.

> In short, I want to get the wishlist of a particular user.

So the most simple solution I can think of, would be to add under each user object an array of favorite cars. Your new database structure should look similar to this:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- users
          |
          --- uid
               |
               --- favoriteCars : ["carId", "carId"]
```

In this way you can query your database to get only the cars a user has marked them as favorite. You can also store instead of those ids in an array, the actual car object. Please see **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053768/what-is-the-correct-way-to-structure-this-kind-of-data-in-firestore/53057707)** more details about pros and cons.

Comment: Pls I'm developing the app with flutter, how do I combine this with streambuilder. Can u give me a snippet code? I'm thinking of using document reference with the data structure u gave to reference each favourite car to its original document from cars collection

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. In this case, you should make your own attempt given the information in the answer and ask another question if something else comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Firebase Cloud Firestore doesn't support querying with sub collection. You may have to structure your database in way that's possible to query.

- Store userid in a array in the car document.
- Use a separate collection to keep the connection between user and cars.

You can checkout this video from Firebase.

[Maps, Arrays and Subcollections, Oh My! | Get to Know Cloud Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7d5Zeic63s)

Comment: How do I use a separate collection to keep connection between users and cars