# Firestore range query on map field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of `conversations`, each conversation having a `hidden<Map>` where each participant is the key, having a boolean value, so I can see if he archived the conversation on his end or not. Therefore, the query looks like this:

```
store.conversations
    .where( 'participants', 'array-contains', uid )
    .where( `hidden.${uid}`, '==', false )
    .orderBy( 'createdAt', 'desc' )
```

Problem rises when adding `orderBy`, which makes it a "range" query. So, given each document has a different set of keys in the `hidden<Map>`, Firestore is suggesting the following, which obviously wouldn't work:

```
participants Arrays 
hidden.`48m6lKjwvKUOboAxlc0ppX2R7qF2` Ascending 
createdAt Descending
```

How do I go around this? I guess flattening the `Map` would be a solution but, not most elegant. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firestore is suggesting the following, which obviously wouldn't work:

```
participants Arrays 
hidden.`48m6lKjwvKUOboAxlc0ppX2R7qF2` Ascending 
createdAt Descending
```

You can create such an index and it will work but the problem rises if your app becomes popular and you'll have you'll have a big number of users. This means that for every conversation you'll have to create an index and this is not such a good idea because when it comes to indexes, there are some limitations. According to the official documentation regarding [Firestore usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#indexes):

> Maximum number of composite indexes for a database: **200**

Number that can be reached very quickly.

> I guess flattening the Map would be a solution

You're guessing right. This practice is also called `denormalization` and is a common practice when it comes to Firebase. If you are new to NoQSL databases, I recommend you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA) for a better understanding. It is for Firebase realtime database but same rules apply to Cloud Firestore.

Also, when you are duplicating data, there is one thing that need to keep in mind. In the same way you are adding data, you need to maintain it. With other words, if you want to update/detele an item, you need to do it in every place that it exists.

For more information please also see my answer from the following post:

- [What is denormalization in Firebase Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258303/what-is-denormalization-in-firebase-cloud-firestore)

So you can denormalize your database and create `conversations` without the need of creating indexes. For your use-case, you should consider augmenting your data structure to allow a reverse lookup by creating a new collection or subcollection named `userConversations` that can hold as documents all the conversations that a user has. For a simple query, there is no index needed.

Comment: I know my way around NoSQL ( just porting my App to Firestore from Firebase ). Just asked maybe there should be a wildcard solution to indexes, but then, after asking, I have figured out it's worthless to create another set of indexes, when I can simply just hide the "hidden" conversations client side as I. Therefore I have dropped the map field index in the query and decide to deal with it client side. That way I have less headache with pagination as well.

Comment: As far as I know there are no wildcards in Firestore. That's good, go ahead with it. Cheers!

Comment: Only downside of it ( when doing pagination / infinite scrolling ) is that you'll "seem" to be loading less documents per request, than what you're supposed to, given some of them are just not showing up, but then I can simply just load more in the next request ( PER_REQUEST + hidden_items_in_last_10 ) or something like that to complement for the hidden ones.

Comment: I never had a use-case like yours but I think it might work that way.