# Displaying user`s photo in Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing an app that show restaurants and user reviews.

I want to  display the reviews , I have the `username`, `comment`, `date` and `user_photo`.

[image]
[image]

[image]

First question is should I save in review document the username or userId ?

Second question is how to display user`s photo? I can not store it in the document as URL.

Because if the user change the photo it will not change in review document.
Note that  user`s photo is stored in Firestore Storage.

What it is the best practice to solve this issue?

AdapterReview.java

```
public class AdapterReview extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ReviewModel, HolderReviews>{

public AdapterReview(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ReviewModel> options) {
    super(options);
}
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolderReviews holder, int i, @NonNull ReviewModel reviewObject) {
    holder.usernameTextView.setText(reviewObject.getUsername());
    holder.dateTextView.setText(reviewObject.getDate());
    holder.commentTextView.setText(reviewObject.getComment());
    holder.photoImageView.setImageURI(???);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public HolderReviews onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_adapter, parent, false);
    return new HolderReviews(view);
}
}
```

This method that create firestore recyclerview in MainActivity.java

```
  private void fireStoreRecyclerViews( ) {
    Query query = db.collection("reviews");

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ReviewModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ReviewModel>()
            .setQuery(query, ReviewModel.class)
            .build();

    adapterReview = new AdapterReview(options);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterReview);

}
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please limit yourself to a single question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First question is should i save in review document the username or userId ?

Definitely the `uid`, since is unique. In case of user names, it could end up colliding and trying to write two documents with the same user name.

> Second question is how to display user`s photo? i can not store it in the document as URL.

In most of cases we are using a library that can help us set an image to a view. For that I recommend you [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). And as I see in your database, you are already storing the "photo" url in the document which is a correct approach.

Once you have added `Glide` dependencies, please change the following line of code:

```
holder.photoImageView.setImageURI(???);
```

to

```
Glide.with(context).load(reviewObject.getPhoto()).into(holder.photoImageView);
```

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear, what i meant is I can not store user URL photo in review document. Because if I store URL in review document and the user updated it`s photo, it will be updated in user document and not in review document. So how to get user photo from user document and pass it to recyclerview? do I have to query user photo by user id ? and how

Comment: What you say is called [denormalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258303/what-is-denormalization-in-firebase-cloud-firestore) and it is a quite common practice when it comes to Firebase. For a better understanding, I recommend you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA). It's for Firebase realtime database but same rules apply in case of Firestore. So what you said it's really normal in NoSQL world.