# Query only specific field with firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I use this code to get a collection snapshot from Firestore.

```
firestore().collection('project').where('userID', '==', authStore.uid).onSnapshot(onResult, onError);
```

This returns a huge amount of data, but I only need a few fields. Is it possible to query only a specific field? For example, if I only need the `projectName` and the `creationDate` fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to query only a specific field?

No, that is not possible with the client-side SDKs. A Firestore listener fires on the document level. This means that you'll always get the entire document.

> For example if I only need the `projectName` and the `creationDate` fields.

You cannot only get the value of a specific set of fields. It's the entire document or nothing. If you, however, only need to read those values and nothing more, then you should consider storing them in a separate document. This practice is called [denormalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258303/what-is-denormalization-in-firebase-cloud-firestore), and it's a common practice when it comes to NoSQL databases.

You might also take into consideration using the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database), for the duplicated data.

Comment: You can use [`select`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/firestore/query#_google_cloud_firestore_Query_select_member_1_) with `get()` to only retrieve specific fields - e.g. `.select(['projectName', 'creationDate']).get()` (but this doesn't work with listeners)

Comment: @AlexL Doesn't work with client-side SDKs.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, my mistake! So the other options are to write an API endpoint that fetches just the data you need via an admin SDK, or using the REST API  with [`mask.fieldPaths`](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/DocumentMask)