# Get random document from Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

How can I get a random document from a Cloud Firestore collection without reading the whole collection?

Given a collection with tens of thousands of documents (users), I need to pick a random one (the winner).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of would be to store the UIDs of all users in a single document, in a field of type array. If all those UIDs don't fit into a single document, due to the [1 MiB limitation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields), then store them in two documents, or even three if necessary. Read those documents, and pick a random UID. In this way, you'll avoid reading tens of thousands of documents, so you'll end up reading only a few. [Duplicating data (UIDs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258303/what-is-denormalization-in-firebase-cloud-firestore) is a quite common practice when it comes to NoSQL databases.

Besides that, don't also forget to update the arrays frequently, meaning if a new user joins your app, add the UID to the array, and if a user leaves your app, delete the UID from the array.

Comment: Hey Witek. Can I help you with other information?