# Can I use in the same project a Database made by myself and a Firebase Database?

Tags: database, firebase, database-design, multiple-databases

I am planning a project and I have the authentication with firebase but I want to have the other tables in another database. Could this option be viable?

A detected problem that could happen would be the duplication of data.

Has anyone done something similar?

At the moment I have not tried anything because I am planning the project, the only thing I have is the authentication with firebase.

I want to do this is because I need to have a local database because users will not have internet connection in many situations.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Sounds possible yeah. If you have concrete questions already, it's probably better to ask those. If you have no concrete questions yet, I recommend moving forward with the approach you have in mind - and post back if/when you run into problems.

Comment: When it comes to denormalization, I think that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258303/what-is-denormalization-in-firebase-cloud-firestore) will help.

Comment: The question is a bit vague. If some users will not have internet connection, then what would be the purpose of authenticating? e.g. if you want local only data, Firebase is likely not the best choice; CoreData or Realm or MySQL may be better. If you can explain that use case a bit and clarify the question, we may be able to help (and prevent the question from being closed as too vague).