# Retrieving data from firebase which is stored under key which is generated in other application

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want to retrieve data from a child "Orders" but data is stored under a number then data is stored under a key which is generated in another application but I can't find a way

this is the code of recycle view where data is being retrieved

```
recyclerVieww.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<historyModel> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<historyModel>()
                    .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("OrdersAdimin")
                            , historyModel.class)
                    .build();

    catAdapt = new historyAdapter(options);
    recyclerVieww.setAdapter(catAdapt);
```

this is the JSON file:

```
"Orders": {
"12": {
  "-NV3N3KYwcjXo5hfZ6h1": {
    "BuyerPhoen": "12",
    "PickUP": "Of-16",
    "date": "May 10, 2023",
    "orderId": "-NV3N3KYwcjXo5hfZ6h1",
    "productName": "Sprite(250ml)",
    "productPrice": "₹25",
    "quantity": "1",
    "time": "12:06:37 PM",
    "totalPrice": 25
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo I want to retrieve data from the key but I can't get into the key

Answer (score 0):

According to your last comment:

> I want to retrieve data from the key but I can't get into the key.

This is most likely because of the following line of code:

```
.setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("OrdersAdimin")
```

Your node name is `Orders` and not `OrdersAdimin`. So please change the above line into:

```
.setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Orders")
```

Comment: Hey Aditya. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?

Comment: Yes I tried but still it's not retrieving

Comment: "still it's not retrieving" doesn't provide enough information so I can further help. What exactly is the behavior? Do you have any errors?

Comment: It's showing null I THINK FIRST I NEED TO RETRIEVE NUMBER THEN PASS THE NUMBERS IN CHILD THEN SO THAT IT CAN GO INSIDE NUMBER AND THEN FETCH THE DATA

Comment: Have you tried to use `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("OrdersAdimin").child("12")`, to get all children within the `12` node? Does it work that way?

Comment: Yes I tried that but then it's only retrieving for "12"

Comment: In that case, you should [denormalize the data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54258505/5246885), and create a single node will all your entries. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: It works but data is different for every user.. storing it under single node will mix the data

Comment: That would be not a problem, because you can query that node to only get the data you actually need, right?

Comment: Can you provide me with correct code

Comment: You should make your own attempt given the information in the answer/comments and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: Hey Aditya. Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?