# How does to apply denormalization?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with two collections:

**Agency:**

- id
- title
- description

**Packs:**

- id
- offer
- agency (map: {businessId (string), title (string), description(string) })

Agencies can have many packs, but each pack can only have one agency.

In Firebase

[image]

Do I have to manually enter the information for the reference map, or is it done automatically? I come from SQL.

Comment: Firestore won't do anything automatically for you.  You have to enter all the data, or more typically, write code to read and write the data.

Comment: I understand. That code has some type of name to look on google? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to manually enter the information for the reference map, or is it done automatically?

As @DougStevenson mentioned in his comment, there is nothing that is done automatically in Firestore. To [denormalize the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258303/what-is-denormalization-in-firebase-cloud-firestore), you can write the duplicate data from the client, or you can write a function in [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions), that can copy the desired data to a new location without your interaction. The latter is the preferred technique because it performs the second write automatically.

P.S. In Firestore, there are no tables, there are only collections, so I edited your question accordingly.

Comment: Hey Lakos. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?