# How to implement complicated query to look up two collection in fireStore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Now I use `fireStore` and `flutter` together.

And I have two collections in fireStore: `Diary` and `User`.

- Diary collection's document model has these field: timestamp, userId, description, title.
- User collection's document model has there field: userId, name, region.

**1) First Step**

I need to get all diaries whose user's region is 'Tokyo'.

As far as I know Firebase doesn't provide query to link two collections.

**2) Second Step**

So now I get all diaries documents, after that, filter document references by looking up User collection as fetching user data one by one.

As you may guess, It takes too much time.

The most problem is I am using pagination.

First I get 5 items from Diary collection and run second step by looping, and 5 items after that, second step, 5 items fetching, second step..

You can know that if diary whose user's region is not recently written, It may takes more than an hour.

I want to know that Is there anything firebase provide for this case?

Comment: With nosql type databases like Firestore that don't have joins, you have to combine all necessary fields for the query into a single collection if you want to get all the data with a single query.  This is very common, even if you have to duplicate data in order to make this happen. Otherwise you will always have to do multiple queries as you are now.  Firestore has no workarounds.

Comment: As Doug covered above, the best approach is duplicate your data by adding `userRegion` into your `Diary` documents.

Comment: you might also want to check this out, a series on SQL-like joins in Cloud Firestore. It's on JS, but the basic idea works for any platform. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G04w_k3TPTs&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLnb2sHdA_8ukNwIyp5jo-es&index=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll put @DougStevenson and @samthecodingman recommendations quickly in an answer. So please note, that in Firestore there are no `JOIN` clauses. So you cannot perform a single query and get documents from two different collections. Queries in Firestore are shallow, it can only return documents from the collection that the query is run against. So in your case, the single option that you have is to use [denormalization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54258505/5246885), which is a quite common practice when it comes to NoSQL databases like Firestore. This basically means, that in order to get the diaries that correspond to a specific region, you have to add the region field of the users inside the diaries documents. In this way, you'll be able to filter the diaries based on the region. So basically you'll avoid performing two separate queries.