# Firestore: Performance of reading user-to-user relations

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, query-optimization

Assume a typical messenger which allows its users to have other users as contacts. And two contacts share the same set of preferences.

I am unsure how to model that in Firestore concerning performance and elegance.

**Option A**

```
/ users
  - id
  - name

/friends
  - user1_id 
  - user2_id 
  - shared_preferences
```

To read the friends list user1 would query something along these lines:

`friends.where( Filter.or ( user1_id == ID,  user2_id == ID ) )`

I am concerned with the performance, assuming that the app has a very large user base.

**Option B**

The other solution would be to store the friends list as a sub-collection:

```
/users
  - id
  - name
  /friends 
    - friend_user_id
    - shared_preferences
```

To read the friends list user1 would simply query the sub-collection:

`/users/ID/friends`

Reading the each users friends list would not be a performance issue.

But it would imply that whenever user1 modifies the `shared_preferences`, the same preferences have to be updated for user2. This could be done via a cloud function.

**Question**

I prefer *Option A* as this means no redundant data and no additional cloud functions to update that redundant data.

How problematic is running a WHERE-OR against a large dataset in Firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How problematic is running a WHERE-OR against a large dataset in Firebase?

The query performance In Firestore depends on the number of documents you request and **not** on the number of documents you search. So the number of documents that exist in a collection is irrelevant. So it doesn't really matter if you search for 10 documents in a collection of 100 documents, or in a collection of 100 million documents, or even in a collection of 1 billion documents, the response time will always be the same.

Regarding the schema:

> I prefer Option A as this means no redundant data and no additional cloud functions to update that redundant data.

It's up to you to decide which solution works best for your app but remember, [denormalization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54258505/5246885) is a quite common practice when it comes to NoSQL databases like Firestore. If you're new to the NoSQL database, this might sound a little weird, but believe me, it will help make your requests even cheaper.