# Firebase - Best practice for handling accessing of sub collections from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

New to firebase and I am having a rough time figuring out best practice for accomplishing what I want to accomplish. To make it simple I have a schema thats something like:

```
projects > {PROJECT_ID} > milestones > {MILESTONE_ID} > tasks
```

So `projects` is at the top level and `milestones` is a sub collection of `projects` and `tasks` sub collection of `milestones`.

I have a screen on my app that displays the milestones of a certain project. For each of these milestones I want to display a progress bar of `{tasksCompleted / totalTasks}`.

Here is some some code I have right now for displaying milestones:

```
...
const [milestones, setMilestones] = useState([]);
const ref = collection(db, `projects/${projectId}/milestones`);
useEffect(() => {
  return onSnapshot(ref, (snapshot) => {
    const state = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
    setMilestones(state)
  });
}, [ref])
...
milestones.map((milestone) => {
  // What I really want to do here is display number of tasks 
  // And the total completed tasks
  // I can't simply just do milestone.tasks.length
  // or milestone.tasks.filer() 
  // Completely lost on how I can get this data without 
  // Doing queries for each iteration of milestone
  return (
    <Progress completed={milestone.tasks.filter(i => i.completed).length} total={milestone.tasks.length}>
  )
})
```

As you can see I am looping each milestone and wanting to display some information about their tasks. I just don't really know the proper way to go about this without having to run another query for each iteration of milestone.

Yes I have looked into [collection group queries](https://firebase.blog/posts/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries) but it didn't seem to help at all.

Any nudge in a proper direction with nosql best practices here would be nice.

**EDIT:**

So this is an example of the data I am getting back from the snapshot query:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Milstone one',
    status: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'Milstone two',
    status: 0,
  },
]
```

What I really want this to look like is something like this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Milstone one',
    status: 1,
    tasks: [
      {
        name: 'Task 1'
      },
      {
        name: 'Task 2'
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Milstone two',
    status: 0,
    tasks: [
      {
        name: 'Task 1'
      },
      {
        name: 'Task 2'
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

As you can see I want to be able to get the tasks back WITH the milestones. Tasks are their own subcollection though, they aren't just an array on the milestone collection.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show some actual data you're working with, and more clearly explain what you expect the final, specific result to be for that data.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem here. What doesn't work about the code you shared? Is there an error message? If not, can you add a `console.log` that shows the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any nudge in a proper direction with nosql best practices here would be nice.

The only way to avoid multiple queries is to put all the data in a single collection.  Firestore can't "join" collection like SQL can join tables.  Firestore can only query a single collection or collection group in one query.  There are no alternatives to this.

It's common in nosql to keep duplicates of data (called [denormalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258303/what-is-denormalization-in-firebase-cloud-firestore)) in order to facilitate use cases like this where all data must be in a single collection for a single query.

Comment: Thank you for the link. That top answer in there was super insightful. I think because I come from such a heavy SQL background its hard for me to accept the pattern of denormalization because I think "what a pain that sounds like to keep all that updated". Just gunna have to bite the bullet and do it. Thanks!