# Firestore data base strukture

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I create Firestore multi-user inventory management. My question is about best structure for it. I think about 3 options:

1. flat options - only products

   ```
   products
     -product1
     -product2
       -user
       -product-name
       -category
       -subcategory
   ```

   If I have 100 users and every one has 1000 product in inventory it will cost me plenty "reads".
2. users separately

   ```
   users
     -user1
     -user2
       -products
         product1
         product2
          -product-name
          -category
          -subcategory
   ```

   In this case there is plenty "reads" but only around "user"
3. deep to subcategories

   ```
   users
     -user1
       -categories
         -category1
           -subcategories
             subcategory1
              -product-name
   ```

   Thia option is to deep for me but it saves "reads"

How would you do it?

Comment: [There is no "perfect", "the best" or "the correct" solution for structuring a Cloud Firestore database.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053768/what-is-the-correct-way-to-structure-this-kind-of-data-in-firestore/53057707). That being said, tell us please, what are the queries that you intend to perform.

Comment: OK so maybe another way: if I use "where" is checks every document and charges for every document?