# What is the best way to upload multiple user images to a firestore collection? using Angular/Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am building an image blog app in Ionic 4. My use case is allowing the user to upload multiple image files to the same blog post. The code I already have allows me to upload one image to a collection at a time. Currently, when the user uploads the image, the image is stored in firebase storage and then the image is referenced in the user's firestore document.

The typescript file for choosing image

```
 openImagePicker(){
    this.imagePicker.hasReadPermission()
    .then((result) => {
      if(result == false){
        // no callbacks required as this opens a popup which returns async
        this.imagePicker.requestReadPermission();
      }
      else if(result == true){
        this.imagePicker.getPictures({
          maximumImagesCount: 10
        }).then(
          (results) => {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
              this.uploadImageToFirebase(results[i]);
            }
          }, (err) => console.log(err)
        );
      }
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

The Service File

```
createTask(value){
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      this.afs.collection('tasks')
      .add({
        category: value.category,
        title: value.title,
        description: value.description,
        image: value.image,
        uid: currentUser.uid
      })
      .then(
        res => resolve(res),
        err => reject(err)
      )
    })

 uploadImage(imageURI, randomId){
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
      let imageRef = storageRef.child('image').child(randomId);
      this.encodeImageUri(imageURI, function(image64){
        imageRef.putString(image64, 'data_url')
        .then(snapshot => {
          snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
          .then(res => resolve(res))
        }, err => {
          reject(err);
        })
      })
    })
  }
```

I am trying to figure out which is the best way to store the multiple image files to firestore, so I can easily retrieve the images. I was thinking that it would be possible to store the images as a map or array in the firestore document like this However, is this a good structure for retrieving the images?

tasks -> tasksID ->

```
{ 
category:
"Art"
description:
"This is a description"
image: 
0
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/wippy-1962c.appspot.com/o/image%2F6cu63? 
alt=media&token=2eab2208-9399-4cf7-89d8-f709d93c4ufn"
1
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/wippy-1962c.appspot.com/o/image%2Fshook.png? 
alt=media&token=ebed3a28-b2ed-423a-a19d-f5849134045e"
2
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/wippy-1962c.appspot.com/o/image%2Fpatrick.png? 
alt=media&token=33062fb2-a3dc-4077-9390-cbeb60a654a0"
}
```

Comment: I added multiple images in .net backend

Answer (score 0):

> However, is this a good structure for retrieving the images?

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53057707/11928130) for the information below:

> " You need to know that there is no "perfect", "the best" or "the
>   correct" solution for structuring a Cloud Firestore database. The best
>   and correct solution, is the solution that fits your needs and makes
>   your job easier. Bear also in mind that there is also no single
>   "correct data structure" in the world of NoSQL databases. All data is
>   modeled to allow the use-cases that your app requires. This means that
>   what works for one app, may be insufficient for another app. So there
>   is not one correct solution for everyone. An effective structure for a
>   NoSQL type database is entirely dependent on how you intend to query
>   it."

Based on the above I would recommend choosing [Root-level collections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data#root-level_collections) as structure.

Doing a little research, I found out some interesting services such as [Firebase Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage).

More information about using Firebase Cloud Storage with Angular can be found [here](https://javebratt.com/angularfire2-storage-api/).

In case you are interested this guy also has some interesting tutorials and articles regarding [Ionic using Angular](https://javebratt.com/article/ionic-angular/)

Let me know if this is helpful.