# most efficient way to organize a json data tree in firebase

Tags: json, database, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

what is the most efficient way to organize a json data tree in firebase since I need to post data and then check for repeated data

I am creating a simple email subscription structure

this model?

```
subscribers
  RandomKeyCode
    email
    created_at
```

or this one?

```
subscribers
  emailAsKey
    email <--- repeat email field
    created_at
```

(It seems to me more readable to use email as a key in this case, and I imagine I can check it more easily when the user tries to enter a repeated email.)

or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the most efficient way to organize a json data tree in firebase

[Most efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053768/what-is-the-correct-way-to-structure-this-kind-of-data-in-firestore/53057707) way would be to create a database where you can perform your queries very easily. The difference in your examples is the use of a `RandomKeyCode` vs. `emailAsKey`. When we are talking about users, the most common approach is to use the `uid` that is coming from the [authentication process](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) but according to the use-case of your app, you can store that data under a random key as well as under the email address. Is your choice whether to use one or the other approach.