# How will SQL database looks like in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If MySQL table is like:

```
table name: members

mem_name      dep_date      dep_cash
NEBU          01/01/2019    500
ASHISH        01/01/2019    700
YOGESH        01/01/2019    600
NEBU          01/02/2019    500
ASHISH        01/02/2019    1000
NEBU          01/03/2019    1200
```

How above table will be created in Firestore? What would be in "collection" part
what would be in "documents" part and where all record to be kept in Firestore?

Comment: You can also check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053768/what-is-the-correct-way-to-structure-this-kind-of-data-in-firestore/53057707)** out.

Answer (score 3):

There's no singular correct translation of a relational database model to a Firestore database model. In NoSQL databases, your data model often depends on the use-cases of your app.

The most direct translation would be to have a collection of `users`, with each document in that collection representing a single user from your table. And while that might be a great data model for one app, it could be a really bad data model for another app.

To learn how to think about NoSQL data modeling in general, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), and for Firestore specifically you should watch the [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) series.

Comment: Thanks Frank.. I will go through your link.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up answer, you will often structure your Firebase depending on what kind of queries you will be running - and denormalizing and duplicate data is common.

Sometimes a visual can help understand Firebase so in this case, one such structure could be:

```
members //a collection
   member_id_0 //a document
      mem_name: "NEBU" // fields within the document
      dep_date: "01/01/2019"
      dep_cash: "500"
   member_id_1
      mem_name: "ASHISH"
      dep_date: "01/01/2019"
      dep_cash: "700"
```

where the member id's are created with .addDocument which automatically creates a unique documentId

Also, dates are a bit tricky so storing them like this may be a better option

```
  dep_date: "20190101"
```

or even storing it as a Date object.

Comment: Thanks Jay.... I am new to Firestore... its a little time taking subject.... I will go more through examples...