# How to structure Cloud Firestore data for an Instagram clone?

Tags: android, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a simple Instagram clone, where there is a page for the user to post pictures and another page to see the pictures that other users posted. In the `Cloud Firestore` I have a `collection of Users` and I'm not sure how I should store the pictures. Should I have a `collection of posts` at the same level as the `collection of users` or should each `User document` point to a `sub-collection of posts`?
I feel like having each `User Document` point to a `Sub-Collection of Posts` makes more sense in terms of organization of the `Database` but at the same time, I think it would be more difficult to get the "Posts" from the `Database`, without specifying which user I'm getting the sub-collection from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the Cloud Firestore I have a collection of Users and I'm not sure how I should store the pictures.

We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. So if you have a clear picture of what the queries should be, then building the database schema might be very easy. Please also remember that there is [no "perfect", "the best" or "the correct" solution for structuring a Cloud Firestore database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053768/what-is-the-correct-way-to-structure-this-kind-of-data-in-firestore). You build the structure according to the use-case of your app.

> Should I have a collection of posts at the same level as the collection of users or should each User document point to a sub-collection of posts?

Queries in Firestore are shallow, meaning that it will only get documents from the collection that the query is run against. So it doesn't really matter if you have a top-level collection or a nested sub-collection inside a document, the Query will always return documents **only** from a single collection.

> I feel like having each User Document point to a Sub-Collection of Posts makes more sense in terms of the organization of the Database.

Yes, that's right, if you add a sub-collection called "posts" under each User document, your schema will look more organized.

> But at the same time, I think it would be more difficult to get the Posts from the Database, without specifying which user I'm getting the sub-collection from.

It doesn't! It makes no difference if you add it as a top-level collection, or as a sub-collection, you'll be able to query both very easily.

Suppose you have a schema that looks like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- users (collection)
  |    |
  |    --- $uid (document)
  |         |
  |         --- //fields
  |
  --- posts (collection)
       |
       --- $postId (document)
            |
            --- uid: "$uid"
```

To get all existing posts, you need to use the following CollectionReference object:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference postsRef = rootRef.collection("posts");
```

And to get all the posts that correspond to a particular user, you need to use the following query:

```
Query query = postsRef.whereEqual("uid", uid);
```

However, if your database schema looks like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- users (collection)
       |
       --- $uid (document)
       |    |
       |    --- posts (collection)
       |          |
       |         --- $postId (document)
       |
       --- $uid (document)
            |
            --- posts (collection)
                 |
                 --- $postId (document)
```

To get all existing posts, you need to use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) that looks like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference postsRef = rootRef.collectionGroup("posts");
```

And to get all the posts that correspond to a particular user, you need to use the following CollectionReference:

```
CollectionReference postsRef = rootRef.collection("users").document(uid).collection("posts");
```

So it's up to you to decide which solution is better from this perspective.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer, I think the best option for me is the last one

Comment: You're very welcome, Mário. Good to hear that ;)

Comment: That's really enlightening. Thanks for the detailed answer!!

Comment: @DorjiTshering You're very welcome, Dorji.