# Data modeling many-to-many relationships with only one collection on Firestore with order by a property of one entity or the other

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

I have two entities: `Course` and `User`. Each course can have many users attending it. At the same time, each user can participate in many courses. Each user can give a rating to each course. Each course also has a completion rate (the percentage of users who finished the course with the minimum passing requirements).

I want to query two lists: a class list and a user list. I want the list to be sortable when queried too. The expected sorting behavior is the following.

- `Course`: sort by highest to lowest and/or lowest to highest ratings, completion rates, and number of users attending it
- `User`: sort by highest to lowest and/or lowest to highest courses attended and completion rates

What I have thought of is creating two separate collections with the following relevant fields for the two lists.

- `course`: each course should have a rating field, a completion rate field, and a number of users attending field. These fields will be updated whenever there are triggers that update the rating, completion rate, and number of attendance of the course.
- `user`: each user should have a completion rate field and the number of courses attended field. Similar to the `course` collection, the fields will be updated on some triggers.

The ratings will reside in a different collection. About the user progress etc, there will be other subcollections/collections to store the details.

I would like to know if there is a better way to model the data such that I can only use one collection to do the above fetching of the lists with the expected sorting behavior.

Comment: In my opinion, your question is a little too broad to reasonably answer, here on StackOverflow. Besides that, please also note that there is [no "perfect", "the best" or "the correct" solution for structuring a Cloud Firestore database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053768/what-is-the-correct-way-to-structure-this-kind-of-data-in-firestore). However, there is something I don't understand, what's wrong with your approach, are your queries returning the desired results?

Comment: You can use the following [**data model**](http://surl.li/hgiot) to get your query working. Reply if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @AlexMamo With my approach, I'd have to do a write on two different collections and I'd have to maintain two different collections so that the info is up to date. I was wondering if there's a way to do a write on only one collection so that I only need to maintain that one on the Cloud Functions Triggers.

Comment: @RohitKharche The one you referred to is what I am already planning to do.

Comment: @AlexMamo Oh to answer your question, my queries do return the desired result with the above data model.

Comment: @Richard This is the only way I think this can be done without introducing any complexity as with this approach the queries will be simpler. If possible can you share more info to narrow down the modeling.

Comment: So if you get the desired results, then I recommend you go ahead with that structure.

Comment: Did Rohit's answer help?

Comment: @AlexMamo Unfortunately, it doesn't. What I needed is to sort based on `completionRate`, `noOfUsersAttending`, and `ratings` on course. Based on his structure, I cannot query order by `completionRate` for the course. Similar issue with querying for user.

Comment: @AlexMamo For now, I have decided to stick with the structure I already had in mind (what I described in the question).

Comment: Ok, Richard. That's the reason why I said yesterday, to go ahead with your structure.

Comment: @Richard You can query order by `completionRate` for the course as follows : `query(courseRef, orderBy("completionRate", "desc"));` does this didn't work for you ?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks. I was just wondering if there's a better way to do it that I missed.

Comment: @RohitKharche Can you give an example of what `courseRef` is? To clarify, the completion rate of each course is calculated with `number of users that completed the course/number of users attending * 100%`. Then, I intend to query the courses based on the highest to lowest completion rate and vice-versa.

Comment: @Richard Yes you can get your query regarding completionRate work like what I have shared in this [snippet](https://codefile.io/f/b0BzfOoNHe)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information you shared, the following data model is the only one I can think of that will satisfy your queries and make the data entities many-to-many while keeping it simple.

#### Assumptions made :

- The documents in the `courses` collection must have a document ID that is either their `course_name` or `course_id`, and the documents in the `users` sub-collection must have a document ID that is `user.uid`.
- The documents in the `users` collection must have a document ID that is `user.uid`, and documents in the `courses` sub-collection must have a document ID that is either their `course_name` or `course_id`.
- Every time we create any document in the sub-collections the `noOfUsersAttending` for `courses` collection and `noOfCoursesEnrolled` for `users` collection should be updated respectively.

Based on the above assumptions your data model structure should look something like follows :

#### Data Model Structure :

```
Firestore Database
├── Courses : collection
│   └── {courseId}
│       ├── rating : number
│       ├── noOfUsersAttending : number(1)
│       └── users : subcollection
│           └── {uid}
│               ├── completionRate : number
│               └── isCompleted : boolean
└── Users : collection
    └── {uid}
        ├── noOfCoursesEnrolled : number
        └── courses: subcollection
            └── {courseId}
                ├── completionRate : number(2)
                └── isCompleted : boolean

(1) - this needs to be updated every time a new user registers for this course
(2) - this needs to be updated every time the user enrolled for this course
```

1. To get courses sorted by *:

```js
const courseRef = collection(db, "courses");
// To get courses sorted by completion rates 
const q = query(courseRef, orderBy("rating"), orderBy("completionRate", "desc"));
// To get courses sorted by the number of users attending
const q = query(courseRef, orderBy("rating"), orderBy("noOfUsersAttending", "desc"));
    const snaps = await getDocs(q);
```

2. To get users sorted by * :

```js
const usersRef = collection(db, "users");
// To get users sorted by no of courses enrolled
const q = query(usersRef, orderBy("noOfCoursesEnrolled", "desc"));
// To get courses sorted by their completion Rate
const q = query(usersRef, orderBy("completionRate", "desc"));
const snaps = await getDocs(q);
```

I have found one article by [Louis Coulet](https://medium.com/@louiscoulet?source=post_page-----d19f972fd4d3--------------------------------) which explains the one-to-many relationship with security rules too, so you can also check that out.

Reference and credit to : [**How to model a many-to-many relationship in Firestore**](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-secure-many-to-many-relationships-in-firestore-d19f972fd4d3)