# Store geo points efficiently with Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am thinking about how to model a collection where each document is a building with a geolocation. I know I should use Geohashes, but what I am worried about is that I would get for each query dozens (if not hundreds) of documents read.
Would using a single document as a cluster of dozens of buildings be a bad idea? Is there a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> I know I should use Geohashes, but what I am worried about is that I would get for each query dozens (if not hundreds) of documents read.

According to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model):

> Firestore is optimized for storing large collections of small documents.

If you think that you'll have a large number of document reads, then you should consider studying the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database), which has a different billing mechanism.

> Would using a single document as a cluster of dozens of buildings be a bad idea?

No, as you long as stay below the [maximum 1 MiB limitation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields).

> Is there a better solution for this problem?

There is [no "perfect", "the best" or "the correct"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53057707/5246885) solution for structuring a Cloud Firestore database. In your case, you have to do some maths in order to see which solution out of the above three fits best your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will consider the Realtime Database for this purpose. 
I had thought that since I don't need lot of synchronization among clients, Firestore was good enough, but in my case may be more convenient Realtime Database, since I expect lot of documents Reads, and not many updates.

Answer (score 1):

I have at some point experimented with storing multiple geohash values into a single document, with the document ID being the common prefix of those hashes and then for each point we keep the exact lat/lon for the corresponding point and its document ID.

Doing this for all documents, you end up with multiple additional documents (I called them geo-index documents) with extra metadata.
Here's an example of such a document:
[image]

So here, the common prefix is `cu`, meaning that the document contains the metadata for all geohashes starting with `cu`.

---

To execute a geoquery, I'd then calculate the geohash ranges that contained potential matching documents, read the geo-index documents for those ranges, and qualify/disqualify the actual documents based on the lat/lon from the geo-index documents.

With this approach I was able to **drastically** reduce the number of documents that had to be read to determine the matches. But on the other hand, it required me create new data structures, essentially building my own index type for the database.

You'll have to determine whether that trade-off of complexity vs cost is worth it for your use-case and other requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is kind of the solution I was thinking, but I thought to group items relating to their location, so that would be possible to make queries filtering only inside one of these document indexes(assuming their big enough to contain all the buildings in the area where the user is searching)

Comment: I get it now, having the same prefix in the Document (so Geohash) means they are closer (probably they're in the same square), seems a good approach, sure there will be some complexity, but maybe there are also some advantages in not getting hundreds of documents for a single query

Comment: Yeah, that was my logic too - and I tested this extensively. When you have few results, it's less efficient as reading the geo-index document is extra overhead. For scenarios with many results though, reading the geo-index docs is far chearper than reading the actual result documents as a traditional geohash query needs to do. In my tests it reduced the document reads by up to 80%.

Comment: That's perfect, I expect that most of the times if there are an hundred of results, they belong to the same area. 
Also I was thinking to make the actual filtering in cloud functions, so that the client has a small amount of data downloaded and little processing.

Comment: That could work too, but you'd lose the realtime updates from Firestore. If that's not a problem for your use-case, that's fine of course.